# How to listen for events emitted outside vue components

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

I am newbie with vue. (and a bit also with javascript)

I need listen for some events from outside js custom SDK.

I am trying in this way  but it doesn't work.

I have a customSDK.js included in my index.html thet raise some events talking with external app.

Then in my vue

```
mounted: function() {
....
this.mySDK = new xxx.mySDK(config);


  this.mySDK.getEvents().taskIncoming.on((task) => {
       this.debugevent(task)
    });
},
methods: {

    debugevent() {

      console.log('task');

    }....
```

I expect to see log when the event is raised.. but it doesn't work.

How can I manage this kind of listener?

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with Vue; it just looks like you can't get your event to work.

Comment: It works inside a simple html + jquery test page, so i think it's not the right way in vue appliaction

Comment: Do you get an error message of any kind?

Comment: No, no error but no log in console while i expect

Comment: Have you tried initializing `this.mySDK.getEvents().taskIncoming.on` within a setTimeout, maybe your `mySDK` is not properly loaded when Vue done mounting